# relevant way to update an index periodically in opensearch

Tags: python, opensearch

I am looking for an efficient way to update an index  say I periodically crawl websites and extract their data like text which I make them as chunks for some NLP purposes ,title,url... and I store them within an index.
My approach for making updates is very basic before add data of an url, I check if they are existing documents having the same url then I delete them

```
` body_request = {
            "query":
            {
                "match":{
                    "url.keyword":source
                }
            }
        }
        #deleting the docs based on the query above    
        try:
            self.opensearch_db.delete_by_query(index_name,body_request)
        except:
            print("new file to load after update")`
```

then I add new the url data.
I think this is very slow and can crash the opensearch cluster.
Is their any other better approach?